# Is it possible to execute a Java code as a part of the project generation from maven archetype?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have a project template and a Maven archetype defined. What I'm trying to figure out is how to execute a custom Java code (or a Maven MOJO) after the initial project structure is generated (for example, I need to pass a URL to a WSDL file and the custom code would parse it and generate additional files based in the contents of that WSDL). I want all this to be a single step - i.e. `mvn archetype:generate ...` would do both initial project generation and execute this custom Java code. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it says in the Maven archetype docs that `archetype-post-generate.groovy can be added in src/main/resources/META-INF/`